# Chrome does not show resize handle when content overflows div

Tags: css

When a div tag is re-sizable but is dynamically created with an image that over flows the div tag ,chrome does not show the resize handle. This works fine firefox.  I know it's a little hard to see in this pic but the re-size indicator is not there on the left side of the image which represents Chrome  while it is present on the right which indicates Firefox. Any ideas?

[image]

BTW: I do have my own resizer in the css

```
 ::-webkit-resizer: {
    cursor:se-resize;
    background :url('/images/corner.png') no-repeat right bottom;
 }
```

Here's the fiddle  : jsfiddle.net/1LtLy5qw/2 
Open in chrome.

Comment: Can you show the html and css for the surrounding <div>?

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/1LtLy5qw/6/ ?

Comment: No. Can't have the scroll bar visible

Comment: See it in chrome:  http://jsfiddle.net/1LtLy5qw/10/